# Regression analysis with constant dependent variable

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients, intercept, centering

Can someone explain to me what's going on in the following?

Suppose we have data with **constant dependent variable**:

```
set.seed(42)
dat <- data.frame('y' = rep(10, 100), 'x' = rnorm(100, mean=10))
```

A bivariate regression model **with intercept** has perfect fit and constant residuals, as expected:

```
m1 <- lm(y ~ x, data = dat)
summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x, data = dat)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
     0      0      0      0      0 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)       10          0     Inf   <2e-16 ***
x                  0          0     NaN      NaN    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0 on 98 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:    NaN, Adjusted R-squared:    NaN 
F-statistic:   NaN on 1 and 98 DF,  p-value: NA

Warning message:
In summary.lm(m1) : essentially perfect fit: summary may be unreliable
```

However, a model with the same data but **without intercept** does neither have perfect fit nor constant residuals:

```
m2 <- lm(y ~ 0 + x, data = dat)
summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, data = dat)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.11758 -0.51485  0.04904  0.74581  3.08951 

Coefficients:
  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
x  0.98624    0.01024   96.34   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 1.032 on 99 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9894,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9893 
F-statistic:  9282 on 1 and 99 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

**Centering** the predictor restores constant residuals but not perfect fit:

````
dat2 <- dat
dat2$x <- scale(dat2$x, scale = F)
m3 <- lm(y ~ 0 + x, data = dat2)
summary(m3)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ 0 + x, data = dat2)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
    10     10     10     10     10 

Coefficients:
    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
x -8.401e-15  9.700e-01       0        1

Residual standard error: 10.05 on 99 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  6.475e-31, Adjusted R-squared:  -0.0101 
F-statistic: 6.41e-29 on 1 and 99 DF,  p-value: 1
```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Algebraically, it's quite straightforward to show why this is the case, but here's a visual explanation. This is a scatterplot of your data:

[image]

You want to fit the model $y_i = \alpha + \beta x_i + \varepsilon_i$, $i=1,\ldots,100$. Your predictor of $y_i$ is $\hat{y}_i=\hat\alpha+\hat\beta x_i$, a straight line. In your particular case, you have $y_i=10$ for all $i$.

1. In the model with intercept, you can get a perfect fit ($y_i=\hat{y}_i$ for all $i$) by setting $\hat\alpha=10$ and $\hat\beta=0$, a horizontal line. The residuals are $y_i-\hat{y}_i=0$.

[image]

2. In the model without an intercept ($\alpha=0$), you're forcing the line to pass through the origin. There is no value of $\hat\beta$ that gives you a perfect fit, as that would require $\hat\beta x_i=10$ for all $i$; this is not possible, as the $x_i$ are all different. The residuals from this model (vertical distance are $y_i-\hat{y}_i=y_i\hat\beta x_i$, so they're all different.

[image]

3. If you center the predictor, you still can't get a perfect fit, but the line of best fit is horizontal* again (so the residuals are equal).

[image]

**almost* horizontal, as the $x_i$ values are not perfectly symmetric about 0.